# install and config openVZ

Tags: openvz

I want to install OpenVZ on my server(fedora10), and then assign a block of ips to each of the vps.  I have a moderate amount of linux knowlege, how much effort is involved to setup what I just described and maintain it?  all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, as I've only ever used OpenVZ as a user, not as an admistrator. That experience was horrible, so I'm a bit tainted to the OpenVZ camp. Anyway, just curious - why go with a "fake" virtualization tech like OpenVZ when there are many other great options out there. ESXi is free, or (if you want to stay open-source), Xen.

Comment: I simply want a free and simple solution, which is the most popular choice?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere between an hour and the rest of your life.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from scratch with a moderate amount of Linux experience, you should be up and running in two to three days, a week tops.  Figuring out how you're going to maintain it, back everything up, move containers if necessary, etc...well, you'll want to devote a few weeks.  That's all if you want to run pre-created OS templates...if you want to run something for which there is no template available, you'll be spending another week or two figuring all that out.

I ran a few Linux clients in OpenVZ for a year or two...until very recently.  It worked ok and was very fast. If I was starting over now, I would probably look at VMWare ESXi and the like.

I might use OpenVZ again if I ever have the need to run a large number of containers on a single piece of hardware (web hosting or application containment?), or if I was uber-concerned about performance.  Otherwise, I'm sticking to standard virtualization because it's considerably more flexible (e.g. different operating systems on a single host; easier to install an arbitrary OS; etc) , and the performance overhead isn't awful.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at something like proxmox: http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page

It is an open source virtualization platform that allows you to setup openvz containers through the web GUI but you can also manage them directly using the openvz CLI commands. Another bonus is you can also run KVM VM's on the same box.